# Is there a way to see the value of a variable as the program is running?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I'd like to see what value a variable is holding AS the program is running.

I remember Scott Hanselman blogging about something like a Variable Viewbox, but I can't seem to find the post.

I'd like to view the variable AS the program is running it's loop. Inside of Visual Studio.

Comment: I posted an answer saying you want the "Watch" window.. but you need to be debugging while that happens.  You want to see the variable while it is running, but not broken at a break point?

Comment: Which variable?  A method local?  What if that method is called from multiple threads?  What if it's re-entrant?  A class member?  What if there's more than once object in existence from that class?  Which instance are you interested in?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I need to see what value i has on a very long for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when there is much data and the logic is difficult to trace..eg . Due to large loops and many variables, then I dump state to comma separated files.. and then inspect them in Excel.

Comment: I just want to inspect the i variable in the loop. Nothing to complex. The loop takes around 20 minutes to finish I guess, but I'd like to see a visual cue.

Comment: I ended up using Debug.WriteLine thanks. Completely forgot about it!

Comment: Then credit me for the idea of manually dumping the state :) sounds stone aged but at times the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a tracepoint, which is like a breakpoint but outputs a message instead of stopping the debugger.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use DebugView from here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

just add to your code

System.Diagnostic.Trace.Write(myVar) ;

and see its value in debugView window in real time .